# Como somar o resultado final dos loops while nessa questão

Tags: java

To fazendo um exercício do curso e essa nessa questão não to conseguindo fazer a soma dos salarios para calcular a folha de pagamento antes e depois do reajuste.

NT. Estava usando folhadepagamento = salario++; Só que ele so registava o valor final do salario.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leitorScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String nome;
    float salario = 0.0f;
    float ValorSalarioMinimo = 0.0f;
    float porcentageDeReajuste;
    float salarioReajustado = 0.0f;
    float folhadepagamento =+ salario ;
    float folhaPosReajuste =+ salarioReajustado;

    char desejaContinuar = 's';

    for (int i = 0; i < 589;i++) {

        System.out.println("Informe o nome do funcionario:");
        nome = leitorScanner.next();
        System.out.println("Informe seu salario:");
        salario = leitorScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Informe o valor do salario minimo:");
        ValorSalarioMinimo = leitorScanner.nextFloat();

        folhadepagamento = salario++;
                
        if (salario >= ValorSalarioMinimo && salario < ValorSalarioMinimo * 3) {
            porcentageDeReajuste = 0.5f;
            salarioReajustado = salario * porcentageDeReajuste + salario;

            System.out.println("Seu salario reajustado e :" + salarioReajustado);
              
        } else {
            if (salario >= ValorSalarioMinimo * 3 && salario < ValorSalarioMinimo * 10) {
                porcentageDeReajuste = 0.2f;
                salarioReajustado = salario * porcentageDeReajuste + salario;
                
                System.out.println("Seu salario reajustado e :" + salarioReajustado);
                  
            } else {
                if (salario >= ValorSalarioMinimo * 10 && salario < ValorSalarioMinimo * 20) {
                    porcentageDeReajuste = 0.15f;
                    salarioReajustado = salario * porcentageDeReajuste + salario;
                    
                    System.out.println("Seu salario reajustado e :" + salarioReajustado);
                      
                } else {
                    if (salario >= ValorSalarioMinimo * 20) {
                        porcentageDeReajuste = 0.1f;
                        salarioReajustado = salario * porcentageDeReajuste + salario;
                        
                        System.out.println("Seu salario reajustado e :" + salarioReajustado);
                        
                    }
                }
            }

        }
                          
    }
     
        
       System.out.println("O total dos salario dos funcionarios e: " 
               + folhadepagamento + " E o total reajustado e: " + salarioReajustado);   
    

}
```

}

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá, tente utilizar...

```
folhadepagamento += salario
```

ou

```
folhadepagamento = folhadepagamento + salario
```

Comment: Deu ate vergonha agora kkkkkk, Realmente a segunda opção funcionou, e pensa que passei um bom tempo quebrando a cabeça e não saiu nada kkkkkkkkkkk